# How do i create an object of the class in my namespace?

Tags: c#, reflection, runtime, system.reflection, activator

I am trying to use *Reflection* to create my objects at run time. However I keep getting

`System.TypeLoadExeption`

> Could not load type 'x' from assembly 'y', version = 1.0.0.0, culture
>   = neutral PublicKeyToken=null'. I just create a new project to try it and it still wont work even though i have not changed the namespace
>   names.

```
ObjectHandle keyword = Activator.CreateInstance("NamespaceProject", "ChangeDue");
Object myObject = keyword.Unwrap();
```

Comment: You should provide `AssemblyName` instead of `NamespaceProject` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.8#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_String_System_String_

Comment: See the accepted answer in the duplicate, in particular the second example.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko that is the assembly name

Comment: Look if `typeof(ChangeDue).AssemblyQualifiedName` returns the assembly name you are expecting. Note, `ChangeDue` looks more like a property name to me. You must provide a type name (class name or struct name).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes FFS it is a class. i am trying to make the name obscure because it is code for my job

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes when i check the qualified name it says NamespaceProject.ChangeDue, NamespaceProject, version=1.0.0.0, culture = neutral, publickeytoken = null. Also if i change the assembly name to Namespace.ChangeDueDate i get file not found exception

Comment: I figured it out im supposed to do "AssemblyName.Type" for the second parameter.

Comment: Try `Activator.CreateInstance("NamespaceProject", "NamespaceProject.ChangeDue")`, i.e., qualify the name of the type with the namespace. It's `"Namespace.Type"` for the second parameter.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes when i did it that way i dont get an exception but i have an object of type Namespace.ChangeDue instead of ChangeDue

Comment: Which namespace should `ChangeDue` have then? Do you have more than one `ChangeDue` type? If not, then `ChangeDue` is the same type as `NamespaceProject.ChangeDue`. Only if you have more than one such type in different namespaces, this could make a difference. The namespace does not make a type any different. It is only there to differentiate different types having the same name. I.e., There is a type `System.DateTime` and you could create another one `MyNamepsace.DateTime`.